Does truncating a file affect the cached contents?
Let's say I write some amount to some file A, then I close and reopen the file using open("A", O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY);. After this, I write the same amount again.
Will this be slower than a program that doesn't truncate? In other words, will truncating also remove the cache lines of the content of the file, meaning that the subsequent write operations will always be a cache miss?

Update:
As advised I've measured the difference, using the following code:
// includes

#define M 1024*128 // 128 KB

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double start = get_seconds(); // based on gettimeofday()

    int out = open(argv[1], O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);
    int k;
    char buf[M];

    for(k=0; k<M; k++) {
        buf[k] = '0';
    }

    write(out, buf, sizeof(buf));
    close(out);

    printf("%f\n", get_seconds() - start);
    return 0;
}

With a script, I executed this code, and an identical version without the O_TRUNC, 1000 times in rapid succession, with different input filenames for each version. I get the following averaged results:



Filesize
Without O_TRUNC
With O_TRUNC
Speedup




32 KB
0.0000603 s
0.0001182 s
1.96X


64 KB
0.0001004 s
0.0001759 s
1.75X


128 KB
0.0001621 s
0.0002640 s
1.63X


256 KB
0.0002554 s
0.0004336 s
1.70X


512 KB
0.0004284 s
0.0007537 s
1.76X


1024 KB
0.0007371 s
0.0011899 s
1.61X



Thus, there is an observable difference.

Maybe. C doesn't specify caching methods, so it depends on the implementation (of std library) and on operating system. And in any case we do not know about the size of the cache. And possibly you are meaning "buffer" (in such case it is a fair assumption (but not sure) that a buffer is kept

@GiacomoCatenazzi open() is not stdio, it has nothing to do with buffering.

This is an operating system implementation detail, which is not specified by POSIX. I wouldn't expect anything to be preserved after truncating.

@Barmar OP may mean (kernel) page cache. O_WRONLY truncates the file by itself. So, O_TRUNC only has meaning when used with O_RDWR or O_APPEND

@CraigEstey That's what I assumed they meant, I interpreted Giacomo as referring to stdio's buffers.

@CraigEstey Where did you read that O_WRONLY implies truncating? I don't see it in the POSIX spec. It specifically says that O_TRUNC can be used along with O_WRONLY and O_RDWR to get truncation.

To the best of my knowledge, a file open()ed O_WRONLY without O_TRUNC is not truncated.  This should not be confused with fopen()ing a file with access mode "w", which does truncate the file.

@Barmar Oops, my bad! Did a test. Without an O_TRUNC, even with a write that is shorter than the existing file length does not truncate or shorten. Apologies to all!

@Barmar: I was intending something other, but yes, we get that it is all complex on kernel side. Buffers as: we cannot write a byte to a disk, but only blocks, so each file has own buffer (and it should read entire block, modify a byte and write when needed). Page cache is more abstract (and we can see as generalization: not just disk, but then huge pages, and things got mad). Too many details and design of operating system -- My recommendation: if one care so much, it should profile for a specific operating system and architecture (and possibly also a specific machine).

@CraigEstey, nope... O_WRONLY doesn't mean truncation.... but conserving the original file contents.  You can open a file to overwrite its contents only and you will use O_WRONLY.  Only when you specify O_TRUNC the file is truncated.


Let's say I write some amount to some file A, then I close and reopen the file using open("A", O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY);. After this, I write the same amount again.


Will this be slower than a program that doesn't truncate? In other words, will truncating also remove the cache lines of the content of the file, meaning that the subsequent write operations will always be a cache miss?

Of course, that will be slower, doing a thing (even if it's the same thing) twice requires more time than doing it only once.  The operation requires you to write the data twice, and the kernel must deallocate and reallocate the data in between.  The kernel doesn't know that you are going to write the same data again, so it cannot predict and save the buffers for next use.  The caching of disk blocks is indexed by block device and block number, so in case you need to access the same block you can get it from the cache instead of having to read it from disk.  But if you deallocate the blocks, those don't belong anymore to the same file, and the kernel can reallocate them on the same or different file (most of the time they are reallocated immediately, as the kernel handles all blocks for every process in the same pool, it doesn't reserve that block for you because it was you who freed it.)
The cache updates are for the other processes that use the same file see changes immediately as the changes in the file are made.  But when you open the file the second time (with the O_TRUNC specifier) you make the kernel to free all the blocks that were in use by the first set of operations.  These were allocated as you were writing for the first time on each write() call you performed.  Then you closed the file, which did nothing else to the file.
When you opened the file the second time, you specifier "I want a new, clean empty file to start writing again" So this enforced the kernel to free all the allocated blocks for the new file.  All of those had to go to the freeblocks list and the indirect blocks too, if any, had to be freed.  This is only on the data structures (this happens in memory only, so if you don't overpass the cache capacity, nothing is written on disk) The writing of blocks to disk doesn't affect running process, but to wait for free space to be available in the buffer cache.  If you are using small files, this will not happen, but if you create a big file, close it, and create another big file, is quite improbable that you don't overrun the buffer cache, and you will have to wait for new buffer blocks to be available.
Observing your measurements, I have tto say that there's no performance penalty because the data is the same or new.  This difference in performance gets from the fact that you have trashed all file blocks on O_TRUNC to later allocate them again.  Had you opened the file again and written, without truncation, the same blocks would have been overwritten in cache, because as you haven't truncated the file, you don't need to allocate disk blocks again, nor free them.  File truncation comes into play to solve the problem of a file that needs to have new contents, and if you write an existing file, without truncation, you will write the file contents with new data, on the same blocks that were used (those same blocks will be still assigned to the file and most probably will be in the cache, making the deallocation/reallocation unnecessary)
You can make another experiment, that will probably be in between the two measurements:  Create a new, unexisten file (without doing anything to the old one) and write the same content.  You will have the penalty of the allocation, but will not have the penalty of the freeing of blocks.  And the numbers will probably be between the two columns you have shown.
You can make another experiment I was asked about long time ago here.  You can create a 10Gb file (full of random data) then make 150 links to it, and start rming them file by file and accounting the time taken by the rm command.  You will see that 149 are almost immediate, but the last will take some time.  Why, well, that last one requires the kernel to free all blocks used by the file, and that requires time.  The last unlink(2) system call will take longer to execute.  The freeing of disk blocks requires some times a big amount of resources to complete.
Remember that system calls are executed by the process that requests them (but running in kernel mode, instead of user mode) and, in general (I don't know if somebody has taken the time to implement the freedom of blocks belonging to a file to a kernel thread yet or not)


Will this be slower than a program that doesn't truncate?

That seems unlikely, but as a rule, performance is better measured than predicted.

In other words,
will truncating also remove the cache lines of the content of the file, meaning that the subsequent write operations will always be a cache miss?

It's unclear how you think writes to the file might benefit from cache, that potentially would be affected by truncation.  When you perform writes, whether to RAM or to devices, the system does not compare what you are writing to a model of what data are already present.  Any kind of write invalidates any extant cached contents of the write's destination, so it confers no performance advantage on that side to write the same data multiple times.  (Compilers sometimes perform optimizations along those lines, possibly eliminating writes altogether, but that has nothing to do with cache RAM, and it does not apply to writes to files.)
If you're going to write the same data twice then that might benefit from the source data being in cache, but that's not associated with a destination file except transiently, as it its contents are being read out for transfer to the file.  Data are cached and evicted from cache constantly, but there is no reason to think that truncating a file on open would have any specific, predictable effect on caching of an unrelated object.

Hi @John, thank you for your answer. I suppose my theory was that if the file was recently written to, the cache might contain dirty cache lines. Any subsequent writes to the same file would directly hit those lines, resulting in better performance than the scenario where the lines were not present and the cache has to evict other lines in order to add these new lines. Now I'm not quite sure if this is true, nor if the O_TRUNC evicts the lines of the file, nor whether this has any real performance impact.

As per your advice, I have updated my question with performance measurements.

@HanzSchmidt, you're unlikely to be able to measure a performance impact from such an effect.  But even if you could, there is no particular reason to think that whether you observe it would be much correlated with whether you truncate the file on open.
